# Why is there not a large power or performance difference between these two air conditioners?

Tags: energy-efficiency, hvac

My parents have these two window air conditioners that are the same brand and look the exact same on the outside. The control interface is the exact same as well. I'm not sure how old they are but I'm guessing the one with R410A is newer and the one with R22 must be pretty old by now. Aren't ACs/heat pumps with R410A supposed to be a lot more efficient than ones with R22? I would expect either the power consumption of the newer one to be a lot lower by more than just 20 watts, or the cooling capacity to be higher than the old one, but according to the info label on the side it is 200 BTU/h less than the old one. Why is this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Newer tends to be more efficient, but not for energy savings.

Answer (score 0):

The efficiency ( 9.7 EER) and rated capacities are very similar , so they should be almost the same ; if the labels are correct.

Comment: Yes I understand, but shouldn't the one using R410A and higher pressures have a higher cooling capacity?

Comment: Intuition is not the best basis to evaluate.

Comment: @MICROexchange6 Did you even look up what the difference between R22 and R410A? It's super obvious why when you do.

Comment: The pressure ratio is nearly the same, a bit less than 2, and that governs the high and low temperature source/sink, which governs the potential efficiency.

Comment: Aren't ACs/heat pumps with R410A supposed to be a lot more efficient than ones with R22? No. The refrigerant is just a passive vehicle. The efficiency comes from design choices and manufacturing ability.